# Incluir campo tipo date/time no postgres (Zend)

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, zend

Tenho o seguinte código:

View:

```
{
    xtype: 'timefield',
    name: 'attendance_time',
    fieldLabel: 'Hora',
    inputWidth: 100,
    format: 'H:i',
    submitFormat: 'H:i',
    altFormats: 'H:i',
}
```

Model:

```
{
    name: 'attendance_time',
    type: 'date',
    dateFormat: 'H:i'
}
```

Campo no banco:

```
ALTER TABLE person_attendances ADD COLUMN attendance_time TIME(0) DEFAULT CURRENT_TIME;
```

Erro ao tentar incluir:

> SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 7 ERROR: invalid input
>   syntax for type time: "2019-10-03T01:15:00", query was: INSERT INTO
>   "person_attendances" ("person_id", "origin", "name", "category",
>   "description", "tag", "attendance_date", "attendance_time", "title",
>   "id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segundo [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52146882/4551469) no *SOEN*, você deveria manter campo como *string*, e na hora de carregar o valor, convertê-lo em *timestamp*. Isso porque o tipo `timestamp` assume o formato padrão do banco, não o especificado no *php*

> using ::TIMESTAMP will use DB default time format, the format depend on your DB culture

A indicação é que o campo seja um texto (`attendance_time text`) e ao carregar converta , por exemplo com a função [`to_timestamp`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html):

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP(attendance_time, 'H:i')
FROM person_attendances
```

---

Conforme discussão em comentário, se a ideia é pegar a hora atual, pode-se manter a ideia do campo tipo *string* e no próprio *php* você pegar essas informações:

```
$attendance_time = date('H:i');
```

O "problema" nesse caso é que será pega a informação do lado do cliente; estando ele em um fuso diferente do servidor (e/ou de outros clientes), pode haver conflito de informação. Sendo isso um ponto negativo, podes pegar no próprio banco:

```
select FORMAT(GETDATE() , 'HH:mm')
```

Comment: Entendi, porem eu queria formatar ele somente para salvar H:i, pois o campo no DB é time. Será que teria como?

Comment: @LuisFelipe, você só precisa de `H:i` (tipo _23:59_)? se sim, porque usar _timestamp_? podes usar _string_ direto e nem precisaria converter.. não?

Comment: Ah minha ideia de usar o time é porque queria pegar o current_time sempre que for adicionar um novo registro, por exemplo.

Comment: vou colocar na resposta uma alternativa de pegar no próprio php essas info (melhor que em comentário =p)..

Comment: Eu adicionei o "s" de segundos no model e ai ficou "dateFormat: 'H:i:s' " e deu certo, nao aparece mais o erro ao inserir. Exatamente pq nao entendi kk

Comment: bom, resolvendo é o que importa :P vou tentar pesquisar aqui e se achar algo eu passo